# Do temporary feats count for meeting prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, class

A [machinesmith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/louis-porter-jr-design/machinesmith) can gain temporary feats using a [mobious weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/louis-porter-jr-design/machinesmith/greatworks---lous-porter-jr-design/greatworks---louis-porter-jr-design/mobius-weapons). An [android](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/android) machinesmith can gain another temporary feat by casting on himself the spell [*program feat*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/rite-publishing---3rd-party-spells/p/program-feat). Can this android machinesmith use these temporary feats to meet the prerequisites of other temporary or permanent feats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, but...**

> A character can't use a feat if he loses a prerequisite, but he does
>   not lose the feat itself. If, at a later time, he regains the lost
>   prerequisite, he immediately regains full use of the feat that
>   prerequisite enables. [Feat rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html)

You are free to select any feat that you meet the prerequisites for, but as soon as you lose any of the prerequisites (i.e. your temporary feats no longer apply) you lose the ability to make use of that feat and any that it itself is a prerequisite for as well.

Another example of where this logic applies is to the [Brawler](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qdj7?Brawler-Discussion#1) class, as confirmed by the Pathfinder lead designer.

> A brawler can use the feats granted by brawler's flurry to qualify for
>   other feats, but can only use those other feats when using brawler's
>   flurry (as that's the only time she actually meets those
>   prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

### Mobius Weapon

From the page on [*Mobius Weapons*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/louis-porter-jr-design/machinesmith/greatworks---lous-porter-jr-design/greatworks---louis-porter-jr-design/mobius-weapons)

> The machinesmith does not have to meet the feat's normal qualifications, but retains the feat only for a number of minutes equal to his Intelligence modifier (minimum 0), as long as they are wielding their mobius weapon.

### Program Feat

From the page on [*Program Feat*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/rite-publishing---3rd-party-spells/p/program-feat)

> Program feat gives a construct the benefits of a single feat possessed by another creature the caster is touching when the spell is cast. The construct must meet all the prerequisites of the feat.

### Yes for Temporary, No for Permanent

Based on the wording of Program Feat Especially the line "must meet all prerequisites" I would say the answer is **yes, as long as you meet all of the other prerequisites**.

For example: Say you want to get *Cleave* from *Program Feat*. You already have 13 Str and a BAB of +1 but you do not have *Power Attack*. You use a charge of your *Mobius Weapon* to grant you *Power Attack* for several minutes. You now meet all of the prerequisites for *Cleave* and can cast *Program Feat* on yourself to gain *Cleave*. Once the charge from your Mobius Weapon wears off you lose *Power Attack* **and** *Cleave*. You could potentially expend another charge to regain *Power Attack* and retain *Cleave* until one or both of the effects has worn off.

As for using temporary feats as prerequisites to gain permanent feats I would say **No, you still need to meet all of the prerequisites for a feat when leveling up**.